# Eventbrite organizer_list_events js returning repeated events over and over

Tags: javascript, api, eventbrite

I'm using EventBrite's events list widget on my website. I have 9 different events in EventBrite that are set to repeat weekly for a year. The code below returns not only those nine events but repeats them over and over in a very long list of repeated rows. See http://organicfamily.co/pages/test

Would love suggestions on somehow formatting it a little better. Hoping it's possible to show those nine events but have some of the repeating dates listed underneath each (instead of repeating the same event again in a new row). Anything would be better than having a long as heck list. Please help thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://evbdn.eventbrite.com/s3-s3/static/js/platform/Eventbrite.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
      Eventbrite({'app_key': "******"}, function(eb){
        eb.organizer_list_events( {'id': ***********, 'statuses': "live,started"}, function( response ){
          var event_list_html = eb.utils.eventList( response, eb.utils.eventListRow );
          $("#event-list").html(event_list_html);
        });
      });
    });
// ]]></script>
<div id="event-list"><a href="http://eventbrite.com/org/7642879257">Loading Events...</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is occurring due to a change in how Eventbrite handles repeating events. Each event has it's own EID and thus displays as such in the widget. We are working on ways to get this to display in a more attractive manner.

I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Okay then. Thank you. Is there a way to exclude repeated events from the list and just show events that have no repeat dates?